# Off-canvas conflict with cover background images

Tags: zurb-foundation

I'm using some background images with background-size: cover;. It was running ok until I added the Foundation's off-canvas-menu. The background images aren't displayed in Chrome.

Any idea of how to fix this?

Thanks!

Comment: I used background images with darkoh.net with no issues.

Comment: Please add some example code to your question. Thank you. See also [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal, Complete and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a problem with backface, probably on Chrome side. You can overwrite it with the following css code

```
.off-canvas-wrap, .inner-wrap {
  -webkit-backface-visibility: visible;
}
```

Comment: I ended up using -webkit-backface-visibility:inherit; but this works also.

Answer (score -1):

I'm sorry, I thought that it maybe was a common issue. The problem is only in Chrome and Opera. I didn't try IE. Here is the code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Test canvas</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/foundation.css" />
    <style>
        .fondo-imagen-bn{
            height:1000px;
            background: url(img/foto-fondo-secciones.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed;
            -webkit-background-size: cover;
            -moz-background-size: cover;
            -o-background-size: cover;
            background-size: cover;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>

  <div class="off-canvas-wrap" data-offcanvas>
    <div class="inner-wrap">
        <a class="left-off-canvas-toggle show-for-small-only" href="#" >Off Canvas Menu</a>

        <aside class="left-off-canvas-menu">
          <ul>
            <li><a href="#">Item 1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Item 2</a></li>
          </ul>
        </aside>

        <section class="fondo-imagen-bn">
            <h1>Example with cover background</h1>
        </section>

        <footer style="height:300px;">   
          <h2>footer</h2>
        </footer>


    <a class="exit-off-canvas"></a>
  </div>
</div>

  <script src="js/vendor/jquery.js"></script>
  <script src="js/foundation.min.js"></script>
  <script src="js/foundation/foundation.js"></script>
  <script src="js/foundation/foundation.offcanvas.js"></script>
  <script src="js/scripts.js"></script>
  <script>
    $(document).foundation();
  </script>
```